# How many positive real roots of the equation

Tags: calculus

The equation is $x^6-x-1=0$.

I try this using the concept of increasing and decreasing. But from this I just found the number of roots lying between any two numbers.

Comment: At most 2 real roots ,  you probably look for the minima of this function and the fact that it's symmetric there seems only 1 **postive** real root.

Comment: Is Descartes rule of signs helpful for your question?

Comment: The function is negative at $0$, then decreasing (up to $x=\frac{1}{6^{1/5}}$), then increasing and gets big. So there is one positive real root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)
=x^6-x-1
$.

$f'(x)
=6x^5-1
$,
so
$f'(x)
\ge 0
$
for
$x \ge
\sqrt[5]{1/6}
=x_0
$.

$f(x)
=x(x^5-1)-1
$,
so
$f(x_0)
=x_0(x_0^5-1)-1
=x_0(1/6-1)-1
< 0
$.
Therefore
there is one real root
greater than $x_0$.

If $0 < x < x_0$,
$f'(x) < 0$.
Since $f(0) =-1 < 0$,
there are no real roots
between $0$
and $x_0$.

Therefore $f(x)$
has exactly one positive real root.